# Error when trying to create a new hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to create a new `Hive` table, but I am getting the following error

```sh
hive> create table salary(id int,name string,salary int,promoted string) 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
stored as textfile;
```

```sh
FAILED: ParseException line 1:67 missing EOF at 'fields' near ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the sentence to create a table with comma separated fields in `Hive` would be

```sql
CREATE TABLE salary(id int,name string,salary int,promoted string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```